# parse html data extraction

Tags: html, parsing

I wish to extract the data values from Html

You can change the value in the html tag is unable to find a pattern.

Is there any way?

Desired results Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6 will be output

```
    <td class="c1" ><img src="/img/icon/code//aa.png"></td>
    <td class="c2" >11/2109:30</td>
    <td class="c3" ><img src="/img/icon/code//aa.png" width="20" height="20" class="flag" /><span>Data1 </span></td>
    <td class="c4" ><div class="tween"><p href="#"  buyId="479900" status="1" daedang="asdf" class="end 479900">Data2  <span class="rr">Data3</span></p></div></td>
    <td class="c5" ><div class="tween handicap"><p href="#"  buyId="479900" status="3" daedang="asdf" class="end 479900">Data4</p></div></td>
    <td class="c6" ><div class="tween"><p href="#"  buyId="479900" status="2" daedang="asdf" class="end 479900">Data5  <span class="rr">Data6</span></p></div></td>
    </tr>

    <td class="c1" ><img src="/img/icon/code//bb.png"></td>
    <td class="c2" >11/2109:45</td>
    <td class="c3" ><img src="/img/icon/code//aa.png" width="20" height="20" class="flag" /><span>Data1 </span></td>
    <td class="c4" ><div class="tween"><p href="#"  buyId="500000" status="1" daedang="gbgg" class="end 500000">Data2  <span class="rr">Data3</span></p></div></td>
    <td class="c5" ><div class="tween handicap"><p href="#"  buyId="500000" status="3" daedang="gbgg" class="end 500000">Data4</p></div></td>
    <td class="c6" ><div class="tween"><p href="#"  buyId="500000" status="2" daedang="gbgg" class="end 500000">Data5  <span class="rr">Data6</span></p></div></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

(assuming parsing at front end).You can parse it by using jquery. try something like this:

```
$('.c3').text()//Data1
$('.c4 .tween').text().trim().split('\n')[0]//Data2
$('.tween').text().trim().split('\n')[1]//Data3
$('.tween handicap').text()//Data4
$('.c6 .tween').text().trim().split('\n')[0]//Data5
$('.c6 .tween').text().trim().split('\n')[0]//Data6
```

You got to provide more details next time you post a question on SO. Moreover you should also post what have you tried.Hope this helps